# How to i find/create appropriate code to send telemetry to IoT central?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-iot-hub, azure-resource-group, azure-iot-central

I have been assigned a [Case study](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIITD.jpg) recently which i have posted.
I created 10 [data centers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y94nm.jpg) as device on Azure IoT central and [configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0buG.jpg) it according to the assigned objective(creating all the necessary sensors and devices to take input in the datacenter)[data center monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pr9L.jpg)
I'm still in learning phase, how do I write the code for this case study in visual studio code so that it sends telemetry to azure IoT central.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorials here show you how to send telemetry to IoT Central - there's a choice of programming languages for you to select from: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-central/core/tutorial-connect-device

You can also connect IoT Edge devices to IoT Central - to get started with this take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/learn/modules/connect-iot-edge-device-to-iot-central/ - if you want more detail on IoT Edge and how to create custom modules with your own code, take a look at the IoT Edge documentation. For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-csharp-module

Comment: Thanks, Dominic!, but how can i integrate my own app/program as image to iot edge device. Do we deal with iot edge like normal device (tuts that you have been posted earlier) or what?

Comment: I edited my answer above to include resources for IoT Edge with IoT Central